# how can I get grunt running?

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs

trying to build my angular app by calling grunt but receiving this error:

```
Warning: Task "build" not found. Use --force to continue.
```

Using the force option does not work. I tried to run :

```
npm install grunt --save-dev
```

This did not help either?

Comment: You need to define a build task. Show us your `gruntfile.js`

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the grunt-cli from NPM? It's the command line interface for Grunt to run.

```
$ npm install -g grunt-cli
```